# Change default "Program to Run" in Eclipse launch configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, ide

every now and then I am launching JUnit tests from within Eclipse by using

> Run As > JUnit Plug-in Test

By default Eclipse assumes you are running something which requires a workbench and chooses in the "Main" section of the launch configuration

> LaunchConfig > Main > Program To Run > Run an application >
>   **org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench**

I can understand why this is the default, but for me (and for all in our team) this is never ever the case. We always need to run our JUnit Plug-in Tests as

> LaunchConfig > Main > Program To Run > Run an application >
>   **[No Application] Headless Mode**

How do I change this default behaviour?
I am currently using Eclipse 4.4.

Comment: Did you try to create a specific `Configuration` ? Under `Run > Run Configurations...` then create a configuration in `Junit Plug-in Test`. This one will be available in the menu afterwards, then use a default after used once

Comment: Can you please explain how I would use this newly created config then? Its not that I am not able to modify a specific Launch Config, but we have like 20k JUnit Test cases and I want to be able to run each of them without any further configuration efforts.

Comment: in action bar, click on the `arrow` of the `run as` and select your configuration from the dropdown list

Comment: Thanks. I know that you are able to create new Launch Configs. But are you trying to say, that I can run any old, new and upcoming JUnit Test with that particular newly created launch config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems a custom *LaunchConfiguration*-Extension is a viable solution attempt.
What I did was to create a new, custom *LaunchConfiguration*-Extension which is 99.999% build on the *JUnitLaunchConfiguration*. I only had to add a custom

```
BlaBlaJUnitPluginTestLauncher extends launching.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate
```

which overrides the

```
launch(ILaunchConfiguration, String, ILaunch, IProgressMonitor)
```

method to adjust the application parameters according to our needs.

```
BlaBlaJUnitPluginTestTabGroup extends org.eclipse.pde.ui.launcher.JUnitTabGroup
```

To be able to initialize the LaunchConfig dialog with the default parameter, I had to:

1. Add a custom `BlaBlaPluginJUnitMainTab` extends `PluginJUnitMainTab`
2. Create a custom JUnitProgramBlock implementation (`BlaBlaJUnitProgramBlock`)
3. Creating an instance of `BlaBlaJUnitProgramBlock` in the `BlaBlaJUnitPluginTestTabGroup.BlaBlaPluginJUnitMainTab.createProgramBlock()` method
4. Overriding `setDefaults`-method (not sure if its really neccessary) in `BlaBlaJUnitProgramBlock`
5. Overriding initializeForm-method in the `BlaBlaJUnitProgramBlock` and adjust parameter there too.

Leading to the following result:

[image]

Comment: I think I accept my own answer for now. Still open for better or more efficient ideas.

Answer (score 6):

**This answer is a near miss:**

<strike>Try this:</strike>

1. Manually create and configure one "good" launch configuration.

Next time you want to launch a test that doesn't yet have a good launch configuration:

2. Select the file and invoke `Run As > Run Configurations ...` (i.e., don't yet select `JUnit Plug-in Test`!)
3. In that dialog select a good launch configuration of the same kind, and ...
4. Then click `New Launch Configuration` (upper-left corner)

Now the newly created configuration should "inherit" the configured values from the the good configuration.

**Truth is:**

- You can duplicate an existing launch configuration (leaving you to manually select the test to launch)
- The Debug team once had plans to support [launch configuration templates](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debug/Plan/3.6/Launch_Templates).

**Edit 2018:**

Since Eclipse Photon, the Java debugger supports [launch configuration prototypes](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/jdt.php#prototype-java-launch-configuration). I just filed [Bug 536728](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536728) to request this also for test launches. Feel free to chime in (or contribute) on that bug.

Comment: WOW. That sounds like a nifty work-around. I will try that tomorrow morning. If that works, I think there is someone with +100 here. Thanks Stephan.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work with Eclipse4.4. A lot of entries are copied from the "good" launch config, but especially not the ones from the "Main" Tab and "Program To Run" section. Its a fact, that its hardwired: if (requiresUIThread()) setApplication(ui.ide.workbench) and thats probably what happens when the dialog is initialized with a give LaunchConfiguration. 
Thank you very much, Stephan.

Comment: Years ago, the Debug team at Eclipse worked on templated launch configurations, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/41353 . Unfortunately, this feature was never completed. I'm not sure if the partial working in my workaround is a left-over of that effort, but I'm truely surprised that there should be a difference between versions 4.4 and 4.5 (on which I tried it).

Comment: I have to admit, when I tried this approach, I only vaguely remembered the two variants of config-cloning mentioned in the edit, but actually the success of my experiment was owed to the fact, that I had no dependencies on `org.eclipse.ui` and hence "Headless" was _always_ used as the default, see my other answer ...

Comment: I hereby grant you the 100+ items of internet gold for your huge efforts in commenting and answering to this particular question. Even though I will leave it for now with the custom LaunchConfiguration I really really appreciate the time and thoughts you put into my question.

Answer (score 4):

if u r looking for only shortcut for convenience then eclipse remembers last execution. After using run as and saving ur run config, just use "Run as" button in toolbar.
besides this eclipse comes with flavour for testers, u can check that out.
Also since you are talking about unit testing see if you can make use of ant build or even better converting to maven based project. Maven has integrated support for testing.
[image]

Comment: We have 556 plug-ins in the workspace and probably something like 4000 *Test.java files. A lot of them are Tests residing in fragments hosting a plug-in with swt-Dependency. These tests cannot be run out of the box, because Eclipse will always choose the "wrong" application mode.

Comment: I appreciate your help though. Besides: The tests run fine in the continious build. We just have the problem running them locally on any developer machine.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a simple and effective heuristic in place, which decides whether or not a JUnit Plug-in Test should be run headlessly or with an application:

Make sure that the plug-in containing your tests has no dependencies on anything `org.eclipse.ui`.

- Without that dependency `[No Application - Headless Mode]` is selected by default for newly created launch configurations.
- With that dependency the default is `Run a product`, with s.t. like `org.eclipse.platform.ide` preselected.

Comment: Exactly! The dependency to "ui"-related bundles leads to the hardwired conclusion to *NOT* choose headless.
In the various "ui"-related bundles we still want to run our JUnit Tests with the glory of using Plug-In related features (ressources, services,...) and in a headless mode.
Maybe next time I will consider to separate more strictly UI-Code from Business-Code to avoid exactly this mingle-mangle of aspects.