# Eclipse by default run eclipse plugin headless

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have a eclipse plugin project which runs by opening eclipse UI. I have added an extension

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications
```

to run that plugin headless for some testing purpose. Now if I run that plugin project from context menu run option. It always run project in headless mode until i do not choose UI launch configuration by opening run configuration window.

Any idea how we can set default launch configuration to run it via opening UI? so i do not need to select launch configuration every time through run configuration window. Same problem is there in case of debug.

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642812/change-default-program-to-run-in-eclipse-launch-configuration/31854034#31854034 There is some insight on how to define a default launch configuration along with some workaround (copying "good" launch config)